Add custom material UI checkbox in column using material react table
As a beginner in React, I am implementing Material React Table v2 in my project. I aim to integrate a Material UI checkbox that reflects the 'Is Active' data in a disabled state. Despite numerous attempts, I have yet to find a solution.
    import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import {
  MaterialReactTable,
  useMaterialReactTable,
  type MRT_ColumnDef,
  type MRT_RowSelectionState,
} from 'material-react-table';
import { Checkbox } from "@mui/material"


interface Person {
  Id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
//end

const data = [
  {
    Id: '1',
    firstName: 'Raj',
    lastName: 'Happy',
    email: 'raj@gmail.com',
    isActive: true,
  },
  {
    Id: '2',
    firstName: 'Jay',
    lastName: 'Home',
    email: 'jay@gmail.com',
    isActive: false,
  },
  //end
];

const ReactTableWithoutCheckbox = () => {
  const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
    //column definitions...
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: 'firstName',
        header: 'First Name',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'lastName',
        header: 'Last Name',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'email',
        header: 'Email',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'isActive',
        header: 'Is Active',   
      },
      
    ],
    [],
    //end
  );

  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState<MRT_RowSelectionState>({});
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(Boolean);

  const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data,
    getRowId: (row) => row.Id,
    muiTableBodyRowProps: ({ row }) => ({
      onClick: row.getToggleSelectedHandler(),
      sx: { cursor: 'pointer' },
    }),
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: { rowSelection },
    enableColumnFilters:false,
    enableHiding:false,
    enableDensityToggle: false,
    enableFullScreenToggle:false,
    enableMultiRowSelection:false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSorting:false,    
  });

  return <MaterialReactTable table={table} />;
};

export default ReactTableWithoutCheckbox;

Current Result

I want to insert a checkbox under the "Is Active" cell.
Expected Result


You have to import the Checkbox from Material UI and use it in your "isActive" column like this :
{
    accessorKey: 'isActive',
    header: 'Is Active',
    // Custom cell 
    Cell: ({ cell }) => (
      <Checkbox label="checkbox"/>
    ),
  },

You can use Material UI checkbox props to handle its value, hope this helps. Material UI checkbox

Yes, it is working for me. The display checkbox appears in our data table. Thank you very much for your help and support.

Happy to hear that
